# U-SQL correlated subquery

Tags: azure-data-lake, u-sql

Is it possible to execute some sort of a query in U-SQL where you have an inner subsquery referencing each row in the outer query?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-analytics/u-sql/semijoin-u-sql

maybe semijoins can help you if you need to filter rowset based on some subquery

Answer (score 1):

U-SQL does not provide correlated subqueries. Best is to rewrite them into joins or semijoins as pointed out by Joel and Dragan.

Answer (score 0):

SEMIJOIN is the U-SQL version of T-SQL "IN", and ANTISEMIJOIN is "NOT IN". Can you provide more details about your specific use case?

Comment: I wish to do something like: 
SELECT u.ID AS oldID, 
(SELECT top 1 u2.ID 
FROM User
WHERE u.CustomerID == u2.CustomerID
 AND u.secondID == u2.secondID) AS newID
 FROM USER.

Comment: If you could provide some sample data and expected results that would be great.

Comment: Another likely candidate for the rewrite is one of the ranking functions like `RANK` or `ROW_NUMBER` but until you supply a few rows of sample data it's difficult to tell.